# get the value of particular element in mongo db array

Tags: mongodb, collections

For a sample collection given below i need the all the street names in addresses array. How should we find the values of a particular element alone ? can we use aggregation

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4c4b1476238d3b4dd5000002"),
        "username" : "pbakkum",
        "first_name" : "Peter",
        "last_name" : "Bakkum",
        "age" : 21,
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "name" : "home",
                        "street" : "588 5th Street",
                        "city" : "Brooklyn",
                        "state" : "CA",
                        "zip" : 11215
                },
                {
                        "name" : "work",
                        "street" : "588 5th Street",
                        "city" : "Brooklyn",
                        "state" : "CA",
                        "zip" : 11215
                },
                {

                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("4c4b1476238d3b4dd5000001"),
        "username" : "kbanker",
        "email" : "kylebanker@gmail.com",
        "first_name" : "Kyle",
        "last_name" : "Banker",
        "hashed_password" : "bd1cfa194c3a603e7186780824b04419",
        "addresses" : [
                {
                        "name" : "home",
                        "street" : "588 5th Street",
                        "city" : "Brooklyn",
                        "state" : "NY",
                        "zip" : 11215
                },
                {
                        "name" : "work",
                        "street" : "1 E. 23rd Street",
                        "city" : "New York",
                        "state" : "NY",
                        "zip" : 10010
                }
        ],
        "payment_methods" : [
                {
                        "name" : "VISA",
                        "last_four" : 2127,
                        "crypted_number" : "43f6ba1dfda6b8106dc7",
                        "expiration_date" : ISODate("2016-05-01T07:00:00Z")
                }
        ],
        "age" : 151
}
```

For a sample collection given below i need the all the street names in addresses array. How should we find the values of a particular element alone ? can we use aggregation
Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using $map operator with aggregation[enter link description here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/).

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$project": { "_id": 0, "data": { 
            "$map": { "input": "$addresses", "as": "add", "in": "$$add.street" } } }
    }
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Nishu Tayal. Perfect!

Comment: If it works for you, feel free to accept or upvote the answer. That helps other people :)

Comment: Can't see that. :)